# Why are cells in the UICollectionView being cut off?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

For some odd reason, the first cell in my UICollectionView is being cut off. I designed a cell using a prototype cell in Interface Builder. I set a custom height and the constraints, however, the cell is cut off when running the application. Please see the images below for clarification:

This is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

This is how it looks when I run the application:

[image]

This is the code behind the class the collection view is in:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set the navigation title
    self.navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Trueno", size: 17)!]
    self.navBar.topItem?.title = user.username

}

@IBAction func handleSettings(_ sender: Any) {

    let action = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)


    let settings = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        self.show(ViewController: "SettingScene")
    }
    let editProfile = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Profile", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        self.show(ViewController: "SettingScene")
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in}

    action.addAction(editProfile)
    editProfile.setValue(UIColor.purple, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    action.addAction(settings)
    settings.setValue(UIColor.purple, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    action.addAction(cancel)
    cancel.setValue(UIColor.purple, forKey: "titleTextColor")

    present(action, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.posts.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell: UICollectionViewCell

    // add the profile header/info cell if there are no cells inside of the colelction view
    if collectionView.visibleCells.count == 0 {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileInfoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileInfoCollectionViewCell

        c.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = c.profilePic.frame.width / 2
        c.profilePic.image = user.profilePic
        c.profilePic.clipsToBounds = true

        c.name.text = user.name
        c.bio.text = user.bio
        c.followerCount.text = String(user.followers.count)
        c.followingCount.text = String(user.following.count)
        c.memeCount.text = String(user.postCount)

        cell = c
    } else {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfilePostCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfilePostCollectionViewCell
        c.imageView.image = user.posts[indexPath.row - 1].img
        cell = c
    }

    return cell

}
```

Any help on fixing this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Add some code in your question

Comment: @DivyaThakkar Ok I did, but I don't think it would be much of a help.

Comment: @DivyaThakkar This is a UICollectionView, not a table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method to set the size for the cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Set the size for cell
}
```